How to make a one-character TextField?
I want to make a game. First I need 3 textfields on where the user can enter a 1 digit number.
I wrote the following code but it's not working as I expected. How can I do that?
import SwiftUI

struct RoundRectView : View {
    @State var text : String
    let limit = 1
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text,
                  onEditingChanged: { newValue in
            if text.count > 1 {
                text = String(text.prefix(1))
            }}
        
        )
            .padding()
            .kerning(-0.2)
            .bold()
            .frame(width: 68, height: 56)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 21)
                    .stroke(lineWidth:2)
            )
    }
}

struct Preview : PreviewProvider {
    static var enteredNumber = ""
    
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack{
            RoundRectView(text: enteredNumber)
            RoundRectView(text: enteredNumber)
            RoundRectView(text: enteredNumber)
        }
    }
}


For a single digit selection, why not use a Stepper?

what is it doing you aren't expecting?

i can enter a lot of digits, but nothing changed

Oh, you need to use a @Binding in the view for the property and in the parent view you will need a @State property for each child view.

So i changed in RoundRectView ;     '@Binding' var text : String
and on Preview ;     '@State' var enteredNumber : String = ""
but i got this error; Instance member '$enteredNumber' cannot be used on type 'Preview' @JoakimDanielson

I missed that it was a Preview and not an ordinary view. For previews and bindings you can use .constant for the parameter, like RoundRectView(text: .constant("5")).

I change my code as following and its worked
So there is no need to define variable on preview
import SwiftUI

struct RoundRectView : View {
    @State private var inputText = ""
    let limit = 1
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $inputText)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .onChange(of: inputText) { newValue, oldValue in
                 if inputText.count > 1 {
                    inputText = String(inputText.prefix(1))
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .kerning(-0.2)
            .bold()
            .frame(width: 68, height: 56)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 21)
                    .stroke(lineWidth:2)
            )
        
        
        
    }}

struct Preview : PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack{
            RoundRectView()
            RoundRectView()
            RoundRectView()
        }
    }
}


How will you be able to get any value out of the view? How will you be able to use the value of inputText anywhere but inside the view? Hint: Binding

You are right so im stuck right now

Stuck? Use @Binding and not @State as I mentioned above
